# How to use a files variable from PHP script to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, image, file

Hello and good day everyone! I am currently trying to figure out how to use a files variable like this:

```
$file = $_FILES['imgCompany']['tmp_name'];
```

and use it in a javascript function:

```
function someFunction() {
var file = "<?php echo $file; ?>"; //just an assumption, but does not work of course
}
```

Thank you! any help will be appreciated

Comment: `var file = "<?php echo $file; ?>";` should work just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)